# How to create an entry with MySQL?

Tags: database, craft2

I'm trying to create a new entry from within the database. The section is defined in craft_sections, and the entries for craft_elements, and craft_entries seem correct after the script is run, but no entries are displayed in the UI.

Comment: I'd suggest not doing it this way, and instead go through the Craft APIs for building out the Craft data structures.

Comment: I concur, and have shared your recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

If you really, really want to create an entry from within the database (you must have a VERY good reason to do so), then you should create a row in:

- entries
- elements
- elements_sites
- content

If you'd like the easier path, use [Content migrations](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/migrations.html#creating-migrations). Create a migration, and then add something like:

```
// Create the entry
$myNewEntry = new craft\elements\Entry();
$myNewEntry->setFieldValues([
    'title' => 'My new entry',
    'myCustomFieldHandle' => 'Look, I can even set a custom field!',
    'myCustomCategoryFieldHandle' => [$categoryILookedUp->id],
]);

// Save the entry. Everything else will be handled for you by Craft's API.
Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($myNewEntry);
```

Comment: The Craft 2 Content migration docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/plugins/migrations.html